# my code is Recycler view inside a Nested Scroll view. I try to first in view in image view. but there is first view to video view?

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

my code  is  Recycler view inside a Nested Scroll view. I try to first in view in image view. but there is first view to video view .I want to first view to image view. any one have a solution.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.